# phpMyAdmin Auth Method and Force SSL Not Working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I've gone through several Q&As on here regarding this an scoured Google, but am at a loss.

I've installed phpMyAdmin and I want to force SSL for login. I also want to use cookie based authentication and the HTML login screen. From what I can tell, everything is set up correctly. For instance, I'm using the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` directive and I have a blowfish secret configured under 42 characters. However, when I visit my page, I get the popup for username and password as in basic authentication.

Additionally, I have the `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` directive specified. However, when I visit the page, I'm not redirected to the `https://` version of the page.

Any ideas? I have `AllowOverride All` set in my Apache httpd.config. I also have the rewrite and SSL modules enabled.

Below is my *clean* `conf.inc.php` file if that helps.

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.5.7 setup script
 * Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 04:36:10 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: My Database [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'My Database';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['CountTables'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking_version_auto_create'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'mysuperawesomesecret';
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
$cfg['UserprefsDeveloperTab'] = true;
$cfg['ShowPhpInfo'] = true;
$cfg['LeftDisplayServers'] = true;
$cfg['DisplayServersList'] = true;
$cfg['SQLValidator']['use'] = true;
$cfg['SQLQuery']['Validate'] = true;
$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;
$cfg['RetainQueryBox'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

OK. I figured it out. As I suspected, it was something stupid.

I used the following package from EPEL: `phpMyAdmin.noarch                    3.5.7-1.el6                        @epel`.

As it turns out, this package places a file in a location I was unaware of, namely `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`. That file was overriding every directive I was specifying in my phpMyAdmin root folder.

I am using `centOS 6.2`. Hopefully this answer can help someone in the future :-)